# How to quote/add javascript variable in html string?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, uncaught-exception

I have tried to use like this

```
$(nTd).html("<div class='btn-group'> <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm' onclick='viewskpd('"+oData.id+"')' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Detail SKPD'><i class='fa fa-eye' style='color:white'></i></button>");
```

But it went like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="viewskpd(" 00cc72988f8240428b25ac5327b2a3c6')'="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Detail SKPD"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="color:white"></i></button>
```

But I am not sure why the `onclick` function that trigger `viewskpd()` didnt work.

I have checked the console and it tell me like this.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Why is this happen ?

Comment: I think your quotes around `+oData.id+` just needs to be single quotes? so `('+oData.id+')`

Comment: it make the javascript variable to be like html @AJDEV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `oData.id` needs to be quoted so it's a string that is quoted with different quotes than enclosing the `onclick` attribute:

```
onclick='viewskpd(\""+oData.id+"\")'
```

In full:

```
$($0).html("<div class='btn-group'> <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm' onclick='viewskpd(\""+oData.id+"\")' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Detail SKPD'><i class='fa fa-eye' style='color:white'></i></button>");
```

Comment: okay ihave edited my question regarding your answer, and it stll didnt work

Comment: coud you explain to me with `\""` and `"\"` thing ? first time i see this kind of quoted

Comment: @Gagantous, Actually you need to know more about `RegExp`, find a good source and read about it, in your case you can use `toString` function to avoid complexity.

Comment: That's not a regular expression @AmerllicA. It's just escaping the quote character that's used to start and end the string: (`'_\'_'` to get `_'_`  or  `"_\"_"` to get `_"_`). There are a few other special characters that you'll need to escape to use like a newline, `\n`. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Answer (score 2):

You're entering some pretty wild territory... script injected into markup attributes by scripts which were probably originally inside of markup language itself.  Don't do this, it's a nightmare.

Try something like this instead:

```
<button data-action="viewskpd" data-skpd-id="00cc72988f8240428b25ac5327b2a3c6" ...
```

In your script...

```
$(body).on('click', 'button[data-action="viewskpd"]', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);  // 
});
```

Untested, but that should get you started.  Put your data in the markup, but your script in your script.  Keep them separate.

Comment: ohhh, i never thought about that..., why did you used `(e) => {` i thought it's `function(e){`

Comment: @Gagantous I'm in the habit of using the ES6 syntax.  `function(e) { }` works just fine here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you assign an ID to `<button class='btn btn-info btn-sm' ...` and program its `click` event in JS?

At whereever the location that you are having `oData.id`, you could do something like follows.

```
<button id='id1' class='btn btn-info btn-sm' ...
```

Then use this `id1` as the selector and program that element's `click` event, which would be like,

```
$(document).on("click", "#id1", function(){
    viewskpd(oData.id); // Call the required function
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need a `string` variable inside `viewskpd` function. Use `toString()` function for it, you must write like below:

```
$(nTd).html("<div class='btn-group'> <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm' onclick='viewskpd("+oData.id.toStirng()+")' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Detail SKPD'><i class='fa fa-eye' style='color:white'></i></button>");
```

The `00cc72988f8240428b25ac5327b2a3c6` has no meaning for `JavaScript` until you turn it to `string` .

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you may use `. Please note that this is a specific character different from " and '. Then enclose the variable into ${}, it allows better readability:

```
let ntd = document.getElementById("ntd");
ntd.outerHTML = `<div class='btn-group'> 
                 <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm' 
                 onclick='viewskpd("${oData.id}")'
                 data-toggle='tooltip' title='Detail SKPD'>
                 <i class='fa fa-eye' style='color:white'>
                 </i></button></div>`;
```